# Tomcat7 configuration jndi mysql connection

Tags: java, tomcat7, jndi

I try to configure `Tomcat`, and `MySql Connection`.

I add `tomcat-jdbc.jar` and `mysql.connector.jdbc` but when I run Tomcat, I obtain this error:

```
Unexpected exception resolving reference
   java.sql.SQLException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

   ...

   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

   ...

   GRAVE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
   javax.naming.NamingException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

Can you give me any suggest??

Thanks

**EDIT After add jtds sourceforge jar:**

I obtain this new error when I try deploy my web app:

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource';

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 

No bean named 'dataSource' is defined Caused by: 

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 

No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jtds driver for sql server, so you need to download the right jar. You can download it from the official site: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

After downloading it, add it to %TOMCAT_PATH%\lib, where %TOMCAT_PATH% is the path where you have installed tomcat.

Comment: I add the jar that you sagggest me, but I obtain an other error, as you can see in my edit...

Comment: @PaolaG your initial problem was solved, good! now, the second problem seems to be related to your Spring configuration, where you haven't defined a dataSource bean. Check your Spring configuration files for the definition of this bean. If it doesn't exist, declare it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the jtds jar in your Tomcat lib, looks like you're missing the jar for this (jtds-1.3.1.jar).

You can download it from [here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/)